# Choosing SIM to make a call

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, dual-sim

I'm really interested in working this out.

I'm developing an app which is supposed to make calls, but the problem starts when device has dual SIM.
After starting Intent.ACTION_CALL activity a dialog pops up to choose the SIM card, I managed not to open that dialog by putting "NOT_NEED_SIMCARD_SELECTION" extra with value: false. But still I don't know how to force slot I want to use.
This should work on API 19.

I found an app [Dual SIM Selector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pixelrush.dualsimselectortrial) where it works perfectly, but I have no idea how they managed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with help of reflections.
It turns out my device's API was somehow changed and it provides methods like `setDefaultSim`.

```
Method setDefaultSim = TelephonyManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setDefaultSim", Context.class, int.class, int.class);
setDefaultSim.invoke(null, this, 0, slot);
```

Comment: do it sill work?